# Unlock with macro when read-only in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to remove read-only using a PowerPoint macro.

I'm writing a macro that fires when a file is opened.
In that macro, there is a process to delete a specific shape.
The PowerPoint file has a write lock.

Given the above assumptions, when you open the file read-only
The macro will be executed, but an error will occur because it is read-only and the shape cannot be deleted.

So I unlock the read-only lock when the macro is executed
When I'm done deleting a particular shape, I want to lock it again for read-only.

Is there such a way?
I know the write lock password.

```
Public Sub Ribbon_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
  Const EXP_DATE As Date = "2021/09/30"
  
  Dim NOW_DATE As Date: NOW_DATE = Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")
  
  Dim pp As PowerPoint.Presentation: Set pp = ActivePresentation
  
  If NOW_DATE <= EXP_DATE Then
    MsgBox "OK!"
    Call DeleteShapesWithName("expShape")
  Else
    MsgBox "No!Exp!：" + Format(EXP_DATE, "yyyy/mm/dd")
    
    'ActivePresentation.Close
  End If
End Sub

Sub DeleteShapesWithName(ByVal targetName As String)
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        Do Until i > sld.Shapes.Count
            If sld.Shapes(i).Name = targetName Then
                sld.Shapes(i).Delete
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

------add
I added the modified source after receiving the reply.

```
Public Sub Ribbon_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Call UnlockPresentation
End Sub


Sub UnlockPresentation()
    Dim oPVW As ProtectedViewWindow
    Dim oPres As Presentation
    
    Set oPVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open("C:\test\example_exp.pptm")
    oPVW.Edit ModifyPassword:="test"
        
    Call DeleteShapesWithName("expShape")
    'Do stuff here
End Sub

Sub DeleteShapesWithName(ByVal targetName As String)
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        Do Until i > sld.Shapes.Count
            If sld.Shapes(i).Name = targetName Then
                sld.Shapes(i).Delete
            Else
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to open a read-only presentation so you can modify it. No need to reset the password, just replace "Test" with the actual password. Where the Do stuff here comment is, you can use the ActivePresentation keyword to modify the file:

```
Sub UnlockPresentation()
    Dim oPVW As ProtectedViewWindow
    Dim oPres As Presentation
    
    Set oPVW = ProtectedViewWindows.Open("C:\HasModPW.pptx")
    oPVW.Edit ModifyPassword:="ExistingModificationPassword"
    'Do stuff here
End Sub
```

Please note: Microsoft's help page on ProtectViewWindow.Edit is wrong. The page currently states this method changes the password, but it actually provides the PW to make editing possible,

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I tried the method you taught me,
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
I get an error at.
For a protected view? ??
Added the source.

Comment: I tested the code before posting. What is the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: And I'm sorry many times.
Added the error image.

Translated literally: "Run-time error"
Application (unknown member): Invalid request. There is no active presentation. "

Comment: In your listing, you have declared oPVW and oPres inside a sub. That makes those variables available only in that sub. Instead, declare your variables at the top of the module to make them visible to all subs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility